# Does ND4J slicing make a copy of the original array?

Tags: slice, deeplearning4j, dl4j, nd4j

ND4J `INDArray` slicing is achieved through one of the overloaded `get()` methods as answered in [java - Get an arbitrary slice of a Nd4j array - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973444/get-an-arbitrary-slice-of-a-nd4j-array). As an `INDArray` takes a continuous block of native memory, does slicing  using `get()` make a copy of the original memory (especially row slicing, in which it is possible create a new `INDArray` with the same backing memory)?

I have found another `INDArray` method `subArray()`. Does this one make any difference?

I am asking this because I am trying to create a `DatasetIterator` that can directly extract data from `INDArray`s, and I want to eliminate possible overhead. There is too much abstraction in the source code and I couldn't find the implementation myself.

A similar question about NumPy is asked in [python - Numpy: views vs copy by slicing - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181092/numpy-views-vs-copy-by-slicing), and the answer can be found in [Indexing — NumPy v1.16 Manual](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html#But-fancy-indexing-does-seem-to-return-views-sometimes,-doesn't-it?):

> The rule of thumb here can be: in the context of lvalue indexing (i.e. the indices are placed in the left hand side value of an assignment), no view or copy of the array is created (because there is no need to). However, with regular values, the above rules for creating views does apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: no it is using reference when possible. To make a copy the `.dup()` function can be called.

To quote https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/nd4j-overview

> **Views: When Two or More NDArrays Refer to the Same Data**
>
> A key concept in ND4J is the fact that two NDArrays can actually point to the same
>   underlying data in memory. Usually, we have one NDArray referring to
>   some subset of another array, and this only occurs for certain
>   operations (such as INDArray.get(), INDArray.transpose(),
>   INDArray.getRow() etc. This is a powerful concept, and one that is
>   worth understanding.
>
> There are two primary motivations for this:
>
> There are considerable performance benefits, most notably in avoiding
>   copying arrays We gain a lot of power in terms of how we can perform
>   operations on our NDArrays Consider a simple operation like a matrix
>   transpose on a large (10,000 x 10,000) matrix. Using views, we can
>   perform this matrix transpose in constant time without performing any
>   copies (i.e., O(1) in big O notation), avoiding the considerable cost
>   copying all of the array elements. **Of course, sometimes we do want to
>   make a copy - at which point we can use the INDArray.dup() to get a
>   copy.** For example, to get a copy of a transposed matrix, use INDArray
>   out = myMatrix.transpose().dup(). After this dup() call, there will be
>   no link between the original array myMatrix and the array out (thus,
>   changes to one will not impact the other).